# What is the difference between "list" and "lookup list"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

[As per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lookup_table), in the context of computer science, a `lookup table`  is an array that replaces runtime computation with a simpler array indexing operation.

The only thing of that sentence that I expect you to keep in mind is that `lookup table` and `lookup list` are, for the purpose of my question, the same thing.

So the question is, what's the difference between referencing that concept as `lookup list` and just referring it as `list`? What's the point of having the word `lookup` preceding `list` (or `table`)? Wouldn't just `list` (or `table`) suffice?

Comment: There are many subtleties in the use of "lookup table" in programming.  And most programmers would not tend to assume that "lookup table" and "lookup list" mean the same thing.  (Among other things, "list" tends to imply a "chained" structure, vs linear.)  And "lookup table" often implies a table that must be searched rather than simply indexed.

Comment: It sounds like you're asking if "lookup list" is redundant.  It isn't, because in or outside of computer science, a list is a **much** broader term that can refer to linked lists, arrays, shopping lists, etc.  A lookup list is a list for looking up a value instead of computing it.  {1,2,3,4,5} is a list, but notably not a lookup list because, among other things, there's nothing connected to each entry.  Outside CS you could think of a dictionary as a lookup list, but a Scrabble word list would not be a lookup list, because there's nothing associated with each entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going back to the Wikipedia article you mention, the terminology used is specifically lookup table, not list.  The use of list, as Hot Licks mentions, is rather specific in programming.

To answer your questions:

1. Since "lookup list" is not common terminology, it would be confusing (and probably incorrect) to use either it or "list" to refer to a lookup table.
2. The point of having "lookup" precede "table" is that it becomes obvious what the point of this table is, namely to search by a key (e.g. [Customer ID]) in order to find a desired value (e.g. [Customer Address])
3. "Table" has its own meaning.  In order to imply the context that you are seeking, you will want to specify "lookup table".